# A table of scraperwiki.sqlite isn't found

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems, scraperwiki

I have a script in Ruby which uses `scraperwiki` gem. In the directory of this script there's  file titled `scraperwiki.sqlite`.

```
items.each do |x|
   if ScraperWiki.select("* from data where .... { x['key123']}'").empty? 
     ScraperWiki.save_sqlite(['key123'], x)
   else
    puts "Skipping already saved record " + record['key123']
   end
end
```

But nonetheless when I run it I get an error:

```
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite_magic-0.0.3/lib/sqlite_magic.rb:49:in `rescue in execute': no such table: data (SqliteMagic::NoSuchTable)
  from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite_magic-0.0.3/lib/sqlite_magic.rb:42:in `execute'
  from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/scraperwiki-3.0.2/lib/scraperwiki.rb:186:in `select'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. The ScraperWiki gem does not create the data (actually `swdata`) table until you've saved some data
2. Once you have saved some data, the table appears to be called `swdata`, not `data`

*Note*: `swdata` is the default but you can change the table_name to `data` using arguments/configuration variables.

Also note: this create-on-save (not-on-query) is not necessarily part of ScraperWiki's gem and is instead the way it's dependency of https://github.com/openc/sqlite_magic works. To see for yourself, look at the code at https://github.com/openc/sqlite_magic/blob/master/lib/sqlite_magic.rb and see how `#create_table` is only called from `#insert_or_update` and `#save_data`

Comment: even if I rename data to swdata, the error persists.

Comment: `Note: swdata is the default but you can change the table_name to data using arguments/configuration variables.` - where? It's a simple one-file script.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp have you saved data like I mentioned in #1? https://github.com/scraperwiki/scraperwiki-ruby mentions optional `table_name` parameter

Comment: You see my code - `ScraperWiki.save_sqlite(['key123'], x)`. But the exception is thrown at `ScraperWiki.select("* from data where .... { x['key123']}'").empty? ` As I said,  when I rename `"* from data where` to `"* from swdata where` the error remains.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp yes, but since it errors before it ever gets to `save_sqlite`, it never saves any data and therefore never creates the table. Do a dummy save before your `if` and `each` statement and this should all be fixed.

Comment: That works. But when I run the 2nd time, how do I check if a dummy record already exists? If I check it and the table doesn't exists yet then I'll run into the same issue as here `ScraperWiki.select("* from data where .... { x['key123']}'").empty?` In other words, I have to check ``ScraperWiki.select(...` first and that can give me an exception.

Comment: I wonder, is checking if a record exists necessary? Even if I save a record with the same unique key 2 or more time, nothing will happen, there'll be only 1 record and it'll be updated, won't it?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp if you set up the keys correctly, correct.